# Are the page rank and backlinks just for a single page or for the whole website?

Tags: pagerank, backlinks

I was wondering if the `page rank` and the `backlinks` are just for one page? If this is so then should we optimize each and every page of the site and try to bring `backlinks` to each of them?

Comment: I'm making the assumption that you're referring to PageRank (the Google algorithm) rather than page rank - where a page is positioned in search results...

Comment: The answer to this question has been given many times in this site but yet this is the first question that actually asks the question. Kinda interesting.

Comment: @MikeHudson: Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I was wondering if the page rank and the backlinks are just for one page?*

From a great article done in 2007 by [Smashing Magazine on PageRank](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/06/05/google-pagerank-what-do-we-really-know-about-it/), I draw your attention to #2, #3, and #9 in relation to your first question (i've included their other points for educational purposes):

> 1. PageRank is only one of numerous methods Google uses to determine
>      a
>      page’s relevance or importance.
> 2. Google interprets a link from page A to page B as a vote, by page
>      A,
>      for page B. Google looks not only at the sheer volume of votes;
>      among 100 other aspects it also analyzes the page that casts the
>      vote. However, these aspects don’t count, when PageRank is
>      calculated.
> 3. PageRank is based on incoming links, but not just on the number of
>      them – relevance and quality are important (in terms of the
>      PageRank
>      of sites, which link to a given site). PR(A) = (1-d) +
>      d(PR(t1)/C(t1) + … + PR(tn)/C(tn)). That’s the equation that
>      calculates a page’s PageRank.
> 4. Not all links weight the same when it comes to PR.
> 5. If you had a web page with a PR8 and had 1 link on it, the site
>      linked to would get a fair amount of PR value. But, if you had 100
>      links on that page, each individual link would only get a fraction
>      of the value.
> 6. Bad incoming links don’t have impact on Page Rank.
> 7. Ranking popularity considers site age, backlink relevancy and
>      backlink duration. PageRank doesn’t.
> 8. Content is not taken into account when PageRank is calculated.
> 9. PageRank does not rank web sites as a whole, but is determined for
>      each page individually.
> 10. Each inbound link is important to the overall total. Except
>       banned
>        sites, which don’t count.
> 11. PageRank values don’t range from 0 to 10. PageRank is a
>        floating-point number.
> 12. Each Page Rank level is progressively harder to reach. PageRank
>       is
>        believed to be calculated on a logarithmic scale.
> 13. Google calculates pages PRs permanently, but we see the update
>       once
>        every few months (Google Toolbar).

From Google's own PageRank algorithm:

> PageRank does not rank web sites as a whole, but is determined for
>   each page individually. Further, the PageRank of page A is recursively
>   defined by the PageRanks of those pages which link to page A. - [The
>   Page Rank algorithm](http://pr.efactory.de/e-pagerank-algorithm.shtml)

The second part of your question was:

> *should we optimize each and every page of the site and try to bring backlinks to each of them?*

To answer this question you need to understand that not only do external back-links create PageRank, but internal links can distribute PageRank as well, so technically you don't need an external back-link to a particular page, but a page of your own with high PR can pass on PR to your own internal page.

That being said - each page should be optimized of it's own accord - written with unique title and content, and in such a way that the page itself would attract it's own back-links. Not only will those back-links help that particular page, but the PR that comes with the back-link will be distributed internally to help other pages in your site that haven't been linked to externally.

In case all this information about *PageRank* starts [people thinking that it's more important than it really is](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/top-10-google-myths-revealed) - please understand that PageRank (in of itself) is only one of hundreds of ranking factors, and more recently, has become less of a significant one.